# Inno Setup installer icon does not show in Control Panel or Settings

Tags: windows, inno-setup, setup-deployment, ico

I have an Inno Setup project. Everything is fine, but I do not see the application icon in *Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features or Settings -> Apps -> Installed Apps*. I do see the icon everywhere else.

The script file does have the following:

```
[Setup]
SetupIconFile={#MySetupImageIco}
```

Is there something else that I need to set to get the application icon to show in the *Programs and Features* control panel applet? I am testing against Windows 8.1.

---

I should add that the end-user installer shows the icon in multiple places, not just in the control panel area and the other instances of the icon are fine. I am taking a stupid user point of view. Each visual instance of that icon may or may not be linked to that one `SetupIconFile` variable. Is it possible that the control panel applet uses a different variable?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Solution is:

Add

```
[Setup]
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\{#MyAppExeName}
```

Specifying the actual ico file did not work, but this entry did.

I tested against Windows 8/8.1. Windows 7 works without this line.

Comment: I have an issue where control panel shows generic icon, I want to change it. I did the `SetupIconFile=MyIcon.ico` and the install output now shows the icon but the same icon is not displayed in control panel, will this fix that issue?

Comment: I am not sure of your question. I just checked my app in Control Panel Programs & Features on Windows 10 and I do see the ICO image. I recommend creating a clean install OS on Oracle's Virtual Box and trying again.

Comment: The path specified by [`UninstallDisplayIcon`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplayicon) is saved as-is to uninstall registry key on the target machine. So it has to point to a file that exists on the target machine. It's not embedded to the installer the way the `SetupIconFile` is. So the `UninstallDisplayIcon` can point even to `.ico` file, if needed, but the `.ico` file needs to be explicitly deployed to the target machine (e.g. using `[Files]` section).

Answer (score 15):

I can confirm this as a working solution too (Win7 x64):

```
[Setup]
UninstallDisplayIcon={uninstallexe}
```

What I really love here it's independent to app name etc. Just pure alias to uninstaller.

Found at https://dutchgemini.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/innosetup-and-the-missing-uninstall-icon-on-windows-7

Comment: But you want to have your application icon, not generic setup icon.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, it adds exactly your app icon. Maybe, for complex scenarios (multiple icons, separate app as repair/uninstall etc.) it works another way but for typical use-case it's quite convenient (and may be generated as a part of tooling process)

Comment: OK, I see, it works, if you set the `SetupIconFile`.

Comment: I liked this option the most because I did set `SetupIconFile`

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 11, you can use the icon file itself.

`UninstallDisplayIcon=C:\Path\to\ico\file`
does the thing.
Worked for me.

Comment: As [my comment to the @Sarah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20792468/850848#comment58064146_20905064) says.

Answer (score -1):

Add

It should be

```
UninstallDisplayIcon= {app}ForwardSlash{#MyAppExeName}
```

I tested it against Windows 10 latest build.

Comment: I just checked my code and you are right about the slash, though not sure "forwardSlash" equates to a "\". I am using a backslash and have been, but did not notice the missing slash. I checked the answer above, before my edit, and see that I added a backslash, but that the slash did not show, so I will make that a forward slash.

Comment: It's non sense, of course it is a backslash. It's a Windows path. (Though as always, you can use forwards slash, Windows recognizes that too, but it's not correct).

Answer (score -3):

I had a problem with your `#MyAppExeName` solution because I use the `OutputBaseFilename` directive. A more elegant solution is:

```
UninstallDisplayIcon={srcexe}
```

Comment: Do not do that. That will break as soon as the user removes the original installer file (what `{srcexe}` resolves to).